# How to get the shipment number of an order item?

Tags: magento-1, shipment, items, increment-id

Once an order is placed, I programmatically generate associated shipments (because of different manufacturing time on my products)

I can then have for a single order several associated shipments:

ex:

- Shipment #100000110 in 2 days for items 1 and 2
- Shipment #100000111 in 5 days for item 3

I would like to access the shipment number associated to specific item :

something like :

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_order_id);
$_items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach ($_items as $_item)
{
    $ciid = $_item->getId();
    $shipmentNbr = $_item->getShipment()->getIncrementId();
    ...
}
```

Thank your for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `$orderItem`, you can easily get all the ShipmentItems:

```
$shipmentItems = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_item_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $orderItem->getId());
foreach ($shipmentItems as $shipment_item) {
     if ($shipment_id = $shipment_item->getParentId()) {
        $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipment_id);
     }
}
```

if this doesn't work, you need to load the shipment based on the `$item->getParentId()`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do not manage to make it work…But I think I have something wrong with my shipments. when i do $_shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection(); it returns nothing, whereas when I look at my shipment in backends, it is well associated to the good order...

Comment: $order->getShipmentsCollection() now works. i can sweep the items of a shipment, but the IDs are different of the IDs in the order… Is there a way from a shipment item to get the ID it has in the order?

Comment: I got it : $orderitemID = $_shipItem->getOrderItem()->getId();

Comment: you can just use $_shipItem->getOrderItemId()